# How to return HTML file in HTTP Response (Azure-Functions)

Tags: python, html, azure, http, azure-functions

I'm learning to use azure-functions and I want to know how can I return an HTML file on this piece of code. (the initial python code for azure-functions)

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func



def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
            status_code=400
        )
```

What I want is something like:

```
return func.HttpResponse("\index.html")
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You need a file from the response ? Like downloading something ?

Comment: No, what i need is instead of printing an f"Hello {name}", I need it to "print" an html file. With an image or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assumed that you are following the offical Quickstart tutorial [`Create an HTTP triggered function in Azure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python) to learn Azure Function for Python, then you created a function named `static-file` to handle these static files in the path `static-file` or other path you want of `MyFunctionProj` like `index.html`, `logo.jpg` and so on.

Here is my sample code to do that as below.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import mimetypes

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        #return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
        path = 'static-file' # or other paths under `MyFunctionProj`
        filename = f"{path}/{name}"
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
            return func.HttpResponse(f.read(), mimetype=mimetype[0])
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
             status_code=400
        )
```

The result in browser as the figure below.

[image]

The file structure of my `static-file` api as below.

[image]

The content of the `index.html` file is as below.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h3>Hello, world!</h3>
<img src="http://localhost:7071/api/static-file?name=logo.jpg"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: for running on local, the `index.html` file will works fine to display `logo.jpg`. If deploy to Azure, you need to add the query parameter `code` to the end of property `src` of tag `img`, such as `<img src="http://<your function name>.azurewebsites.net/api/static-file?name=logo.jpg&code=<your code for /api/static-file>"></img>`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was exactly what I wanted and more!

Comment: what if here instead of content i want to get a file .. It means when i hit the URL .kml file (in my case) should download ... With above code i am getting the content of the file but i want file to downloaded

Answer (score 2):

I did simple, do not mind the content (uploading a file), it is not working that way :)

```
  if command:
        return func.HttpResponse(status_code=200,headers={'content-type':'text/html'}, 
        body=
"""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <form enctype = "multipart/form-data" action = "returnNameTrigger?save_file.py" method = "post">
   <p>File: <input type = "file" name = "filename" /></p>
   <p><input type = "submit" value = "Upload" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
""")
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer no longer works. Now you need to use the context to find the correct folder. Something like the code below should work.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func 
import mimetypes


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('processed request for home funciton')
    # Returns /projectRoot/functionName/static/index.html
    filename = f"{context.function_directory}/static/index.html"
    
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
        return func.HttpResponse(f.read(), mimetype=mimetype[0])
```